# How to select in R all columns with a common tag?

Tags: r, apache-spark-sql, sql-like, sparkr

I have a `SparkDataFrame` with hundreds of columns and I would like to only select those with the word "time" on it.

**Instead of doing something like this** having to write all the names of the column manually:

```
df_selection <- SparkR::select(df, "TRT_time", "Flight_time", "SS_time", ...)
```

**I would like to do something like:**

```
df_selection <- SparkR::select(df, like('^time.*?'))
```

**Is there a nice way of doing this in SparkR?** An equivalent for the SQL like operator? I'm a total begginer in R, sorry if it is quite simple question but I couldn't get my brain around it.

Thank you!

Comment: `df_selection<-df[,grepl("time", colnames(df))]`

Comment: This does not work for me:

Error in column(callJStatic("org.apache.spark.sql.functions", "col", x)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'column': Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the column names using `names()`, even if it is a `SparkDataFrame`. And then you can use `grepl()` to find matches to a pattern.

```
cols <- names(df)

head(select(df, cols[grepl('^time.*?', names(df))]))
```

Which returns:

```
            time_hour
1 2013-01-01 06:00:00
2 2013-01-01 06:00:00
3 2013-01-01 06:00:00
4 2013-01-01 06:00:00
5 2013-01-01 07:00:00
6 2013-01-01 06:00:00
```

---

*Update after comment:*

The best thing would be to include it with an `OR` i.e. `'|'` where you subset `col`.

```
head(SparkR::select(df, cols[grepl('^time.*?', names(df)) | cols == "airline_iata"]))
```

Note: You could also create a character vector like this `c(cols[grepl('^time.*?', names(df))], 'airline_iata')` but Spark throws an error if a column name is not found. airline_iata'`is not in`names(df)`.

Comment: Thanks! This works as I wanted!. One last thing: If I also want to select a column that has no "time" on the name in the same selection. How should I do it?
I am triyng this but  it does not work:
select(df, cols[grepl("time", names(df))], "airline_iata")